# Running a js function in html while the script tag has a defer attribute set

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, deferred

I the **`defer`** attribute of the **`script`** tag in the **`<head>`** section of HTML files.  This almost always means that I cannot run js functions in the HTML since the js file is only loaded after the HTML file has been loaded..

I have run into a situation where I needed to run a js function in my HTML file, but would not want to remove the defer attribute from the script tag because of other functions in the js file. I looked at the possibility of using **`async`**, but it also was not helpful.

Any idea on how this could be done... other than using defer? I would still like to keep the **`script`** tag in the **`head`**, but going that way would mean that I have no open (non-function based) instructions in the linked js file... which is not always ideal.

Here is a sample of the HTML file

**temp.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="temp.js" defer></script>
    <title>Defer et al</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        runThisFunction('Home');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is a sample of the js file

**temp.js**

```js
function runThisFunction(varin) {
    console.log(varin);
}
```

If I remove the defer from the js file, the function will run; if I leave it there, or use async instead, the function will not run because it has not loaded yet.

Any assistance in this small issue will be appreciated.

Comment: What is preventing you from using multiple scripts?

Answer (score 0):

The *best* way to do this would be to refactor your script to contain an entry point in a function, and run that function once the DOM loads. Instead of, for example

```
// temp.js

function runThisFunction(varin) {
    console.log(varin);
}

document.querySelector('.foo').textContent = 'doing stuff';
// other code here
```

put all of the functionality that depends on the page being loaded into its own function:

```
// temp.js

function runThisFunction(varin) {
    console.log(varin);
}

function init() {
  document.querySelector('.foo').textContent = 'doing stuff';
  // other code here
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

This way, if you also remove the `defer` attribute, `runThisFunction` will be available immediately, but the other parts of your code won't run until the page is loaded.